# "The name is" or "My name is"

Tags: formality, expression-choice

What is the fundamental difference between saying "The name is X" or " My name is X" to introduce yourself?

It seems that both versions are used in movies/tv shows, but as far as I recall, no one ever mentioned the former in my English lectures.
Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: 1. *The name is Bond. James Bond.* 2. *My name is James Bond, but call me Jim*. 3. *I'm called James*. 4. *I'm Jimmy.* Lots of different ways of saying the same thing. No1 is rarely heard outside spy movies.Use 2,3, and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the sentences are correct grammatically.
Use of **My name is X** Sentence is widespread.

Also, if you try to analyse both the sentences more deeply you will find that-

1.When you use **My name is X**, the emphasis is on **you**.

2.When you use **The name is X**, the emphasis is on the **name**.

**The name is Bond, James Bond.**- Here the name seems to outshine the person.